# How to detect orientation with accelerometer while vehicle has variable acceleration?

Tags: orientation, accelerometer, gyroscope, kalman-filter, imu

According to my research, I saw that, in order to detect the angular orientation AHRS uses gyro and accelerometer. Only gyro does not work well because of integration drift. Only accelerometer also does not work because of vibrations and vehicle accelerations. That's why sensor fusion algorithms like kalman filter are used to have a better guess. But the thing is, what if we have a fighter jet that operates at excessive acceleration? In this case, is it possible to extract the gravitation vector from the accelerometer data? If we cant that it means that at that operation we only rely on gyro which will drift after a while.

What kind of algorithms are used in these vehicles to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There exists very performant accelerometers that can detect these kind of accelerations.
I don't see why a kalman filter could not be use in this case.